# How to write API with help of typescript , graphql in node environment

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql

I had new project that requirement is write API using node.js environment with help of typescript language and graphql. I am not have awareness about graphql.
How i could implement typescript and graphql in node environment. Then which  database is suitable to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good article for a tutorial and introduction using typescript and GraphQL in a project: https://hashnode.com/post/building-a-nodejs-api-with-typescript-and-graphql-cjrrojjx200uqrxs1ngtitx9p

You can choose any Database technology you would like too, but it has to fit the project requirements and hosting situation for the project. I would suggest using mongoDB (NoSQL)if you have to deal with a lot of JSON Objects.

But you also can use SQL-DB and framework like [sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html)